# Como deixar uma pagina toda clicavel ligada a um botão?

Tags: php, javascript, html

como posso deixar uma pagina toda clicavel ligada a um botão? Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/u06oowLn/ quando a pessoa clicar em qualquer area do site clique no botão play ou no video do youtube que vai ta na pagina, como se fosse um anuncio invisivel em toda a pagina, deixando clicavel

Comment: Troque `"#btnPlay"` por `document` no jquery

Comment: Pergunta: qual é a finalidade deste código?

Answer (score 1):

[**sfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ugbg5bwt/)

Basta associar o evento click a  `document` ao invés do id do botão  `#btnPlay`

Biblioteca

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

Script: você deve setar o vídeo em  `videoId: 'YeiYa70RxRc'`

```
$(window).load(function(){
var player = new YT.Player('player', {
    width: 540,
    height: 320,
    videoId: 'YeiYa70RxRc'
});

$(document).on("click", function() {
    player.playVideo();
});
});
```

Html

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

Comment: Editei a resposta e coloquei o jsfidle.Mostre o que você tentou fazer

Comment: Faltou a biblioteca, faça assim abre o http://jsfiddle.net/u06oowLn/  substitue os codigos pelos seus e depois clica em fork que vai te dar um novo url com seu exemplo. Mas se vc fizer como está na resposta e publicar no seu servidor, vai funcionar. Eu também não sei como colocar a biblioteca nesse jsfidle.

Comment: @ThiagoSC coloquei o seu video no jsfidle da resposta  http://jsfiddle.net/ugbg5bwt/

Comment: Não sou vendedor não. Apenas querendo aprender ensinando. Fique a vontade, se eu puder ajudá-lo ajudarei.

Comment: Não entendi bem, o video dentro de um iframe? e o video invisivel ou o iframe invisivel? Clicando na area da pagina o video se tornaria visivel? ou o iframe se tornaria visivel?

Answer (score 0):

Da para atrelar um evento de click na window ou no document, com javascript, assim quando qualquer lugar da tela ou do documento for clicado esse evento será executado

```
$(window).click(function() {
    console.log("Botão clicado")
});
```

ou

```
$(document).click(function() {
console.log("Botão clicado")
});
```